Relation between Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds 5-6 and Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds 15.32
Sorry, I just need a sanity-check on whether I'm correctly interpreting the relationship between these two results:
Theorem 5-6 (Spivak's Calulus on Manifolds): Let $M$ be an oriented two-dimensional manifold (or manifold-with boundary) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $n$ be the unit outward normal. Then
$$dA = n^1dy\wedge dz + n^2dz\wedge dx + n^3dz\wedge dx.$$
Proposition 15.32 (Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds): Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold with or without boundary, let $S\subset M$ be an immersed hypersurface with or without boundary, and let $h$ denote the induced metric on $S$. Suppose $N$ is a smooth unit normal vector field along $S$. With respect to the orientation of $S$ determined by $N$, the volume form of $(S,h)$ is given by
$$\omega_h = \iota^*_S(N\lrcorner\ \omega_g)$$
where

$\iota$ is the (smooth) inclusion map $S\to M$.
$\omega_g$ is the volume form on $M$.
$N\lrcorner\ \omega_g$ is the interior product of $N$ and $\omega_g$.


Is $dA$ the volume form $\iota_S^*(N\lrcorner\ \omega_g)$ on the two-dimensional manifold $S$ induced from the volume form $\omega_g = dV$ in the manifold $\mathbb{R}^3$?
Given two tangent vectors $v,w$ at $p\in S$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\iota_S^*(N\lrcorner\ \omega_g)_p(v,w) & = (N\lrcorner\ \omega_g)_p(d\iota_S(v),d\iota_S(v)) \\
& = (N\lrcorner\ \omega_g)_p(v,w)\\
& = (\omega_g)_p(N_p,v,w)\\
& = dV_p(N_p,v,w)\\
& = (dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)(N_p,v,w)\\
& = \big[(dx\otimes dy\otimes dz + - dx\otimes dz\otimes dy)\\
& + (dy\otimes dz\otimes dx - dy\otimes dx\otimes dz)\\
& + (dz\otimes dx\otimes dy - dz\otimes dy\otimes dx)\big](N_p,v,w)\\
& = \big[N_p^1dy\wedge dz\\
& + N_p^2dz\wedge dx\\
& + N_p^3dx\wedge dy\big](v,w)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
which is the equation in Spivak's, right?

Yes, this looks correct.
